# Importing modules in Angular 2 with Django

Tags: django, angular, npm, angular-module

I have some trouble importing a module in an Angular 2 app served using Django. I've been working on combining Angular 2 and Django, loosely following this page: https://4sw.in/blog/2016/django-angular2-tutorial/. In **settings.py** of Django I added

```
ANGULAR_URL = '/ng/'
ANGULAR_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'ngApp/src')
```

and I add a line

```
baseURL: '/ng/',
```

to **systemjs.config.js**. After changing the index.html to this:

```
{% load static %}

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">
    <base href="/">
    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="{{ ANGULAR_URL }}node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="{{ ANGULAR_URL }}node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ ANGULAR_URL }}node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="{{ ANGULAR_URL }}systemjs.config.js"></script>
    {# Write your django logics here #}
    <script>
      window.ANGULAR_URL = "{{ ANGULAR_URL }}";
      System.import('/ng/main.js').catch(function(err){
          console.error(err);
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

when I go to **localhost:8000**, my app loads well. However, when I load an extra module (Google Maps for Angular 2) by adding:

```
'angular2-google-maps': 'npm:angular2-google-maps/core/',
```

to map{} in **systemjs.config.js** and

```
import { AgmCoreModule } from 'angular2-google-maps';
```

in **app.module.ts**, *npm start* produces an error

```
src/app/app.module.ts(7,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2-google-maps'.
```

even though it's installed and in the folder node_modules. My folders look as follows:

```
/DjangoProject
 - settings.py
 - /ngApp
    -- /src
        --- systemjs.config.js
        --- /node_modules
            ---- /angular2-google-maps
        --- main.ts
        --- /app
            ---- app.module.ts
            ---- app.component.ts
 - /core
    -- /templates
        --- index.html
```

There's probably a setting somewhere I overlooked, but this has been bugging me for a while and I can't figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: Whay dont you use Angular-CLI?